# IIS web service need to know what ports are being used

Tags: iis, web-server

I inherited a legacy system with no documentation. There is a web service that is sending queries to SQL Server. It stopped working several months ago and I just now found out.

I think my antivirus is blocking the Web Service port but I can't seem to find out which port it is using. Netstat didn't identify it. Couldn't find it in the IIS management console but I'm sure it was in there somewhere.

Comment: "There is a web service that is sending queries to SQL Server." Then you should check if the SQL Server ports are not opened.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are two steps involved in this legacy system. Step one is between the client and the web service. This probably uses port 80 or 443, or maybe both. You can find this by looking at the bindings in the IIS management console.

Step two is between the web service and the SQL server. This probably uses port 1433, if it is a default SQL instance. And it probably uses an arbitrary port in the 49152 to 65535 range if it is a named instance. You can find this by looking at the SQL server. There are several places to find it. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297475/how-to-find-sql-server-running-port) describes them.